# Ternary expansions

Tags: analysis

How to prove that if two numbers $x,y \in [0,1]$ have ternary expansions:
$$x=\left( 0,x_1 x_2 x_3 \ldots \right)_{3}$$
$$y=\left( 0,y_1 y_2 y_3 \ldots \right)_{3}$$
where $x_i,y_j \in \{0,1,2\}$
and $|x-y| < \frac{1}{3^{N+1}}$,
then $x_n=y_n$ for $n=1, \ldots , N$. Please help me.

Comment: You cannot prove things that are not true.

Comment: The prove of continuity of Cantor function in http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~jwsands/333f12/nonborelmeasset.pdf is incorrect?

Comment: Consider $x=(0,0222\cdots)_3$ and $y=(0,1000\cdots)_3$, each repeating the same digit indefinitely.  Then $|x-y|=0$, even though $x_1 \ne y_1$.  Of course in the Cantor function proof, where you do not allow digit $1$, there is no counterexample like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally not true: for instance, take $x_n=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3^n}, y_n=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^n}$. Then $|x_n-y_n|=\frac{2}{3^n}$, which gets arbitrarily small, but the first digit in their ternary expansion will be respectively $0$ and $1$ for all $n\geq 2$.